# Is there a way to drop gold without the console or mods?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Individual gold pieces (A.K.A. Septims) can be found, coin purses can be found, gold can be found within containers, pickpocketed from living persons, and gold can be stored from the player into a container (or pickpocketed onto a living person). However, once individual gold pieces or coin purses are looted, I know of no way to drop individual gold pieces or coin purses, as they are converted into a player value, rather than being or remaining a physical object with which one may interact.

Particularly without the console or mods, is there a way to generate individual gold pieces that can be moved and looted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not possible to drop individual gold pieces (or bags, et cetera) onto the ground in the vanilla game (or via any of the official DLC). You can *only* store it into another container.

The only way to drop gold is via the console (`player drop F <count>`) or [with a mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/27792/?).

Answer (score -1):

Via console, "player.drop" will cause the player-character (i.e. you) to drop the item whose RefID follows and as many of it as follows that. So, "player.drop F 1" will cause you to drop 1 Septim.

Comment: I voted down because you failed to answer your own question properly :P

Comment: lolk. It's a preemptive answer to prevent others from answering this way and an answer before I modified the question to be without console commands. I don't plan on accepting it.

Comment: The question specifically asked "Particularly without the console or mods, is there a way to generate individual gold pieces that can be moved and looted?". Please read carefully before answering.

Comment: @KimMinseo It's my own question. I posted this option to prevent others from answering the same way and to inform others how to do it if they don't mind using the console. Originally, I think my question didn't include those stipulations.

Comment: @NiteCyper Sorry, I didn't see it...